# Strategy for OS X and downlevel version of C++11 library?

Tags: c++, c++11, runtime, osx

I think I've found myself in a situation where things are quickly spiraling out of control, and I'd like to get some feedback to select a way to proceed.

***BACKGROUND***

I'm working with a library based upon C++03. The library is cross-platform and supports multiple compilers. There are no external dependencies or prerequisites (i.e., no need for Autotools, Cmake, Boost, etc). We started testing with `std=c++11` and found some things needed to be fixed. For example, `auto_ptr` was deprecated, so we needed to switch to `unique_ptr` if `__cplusplus >= 201103L`.

The switch to `unique_ptr` was relatively easy, except on OS X. OS X advertises `__cplusplus` as `201103L`, but its a woefully deficient C++11 runtime library (I'm not even going to use the word *"standard"* in that sentence). Worse, if someone builds the latest LLVM/Clang from sources on OS X *without libcxx*, then the same deficiencies exist because the new Clang uses the old libraries.

To resolve the `auto_ptr` issue, we jumped through some hoops that ended in the following code. While the code below looks clean, the preprocessor is working overtime to determine when it should to defined `MYLIB_HAVE_UNIQUE_PTR` and `MYLIB_HAVE_TEMPLATE_ALIAS` due to OS X.

```
// The result is MyLib::auto_ptr in both cases
#if defined(MYLIB_HAVE_UNIQUE_PTR) && defined(MYLIB_HAVE_TEMPLATE_ALIAS)
  template<typename T>
    using auto_ptr = std::unique_ptr<T>;
#else
  using std::auto_ptr;
#endif
```

We are now trying to provide move semantics guarded on `__cplusplus` because there are two to five classes that would benefit. However, OS X is giving us trouble again because it lacks `std::move`. I suspect its going to have problems with Rvalues and Rvalue References, too.

We asked the Clang developers how to feature test for `std::move` at [How to test for std::move (intersection of Apple and Clang)](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/cfe-dev/2015-July/044488.html). One of the Clang developers suggested we roll our own, but I'm beginning to think its a losing battle based upon GNU's source code for [move.h](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-api-4.5/a00936_source.html). For example a quick `grep -IR is_lvalue_reference /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/` reveals no hits.

***STRATEGIES***

I think our choices are (1) drop support for OS X altogether; (2) treat OS X as C++03; (3) roll our own implementation for missing C++11 features on OS X; or (4) switch to Autotools or Cmake for feature detection.

(1) is categorically not going to happen. (2) seems reasonable. (3) seems like a lot of work. (4) is not going to happen because it introduces external dependencies.

For (2), I believe the test is as easy as:

```
//  For Microsoft's cl.exe, pivot on _MSC_VER, not __cplusplus.
#if (_MSC_VER >= 1600) || (__cplusplus >= 201103L)
# define MYLIB_CXX11 1
#endif

// Ancient C++ runtime library; unset it because its too much trouble.
// Thanks to Jonathan Wakely for the `__has_include(<forward_list>)`
//     test. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/31655462.
// TODO: test under Xcode 3, where g++ is really g++.
#if defined(__clang__)
#    if !(__has_include(<forward_list>))
#        undef MYLIB_CXX11
#    endif
#endif
```

Then back to canonicalized feature detection:

```
#if MYLIB_CXX11

  // Everyone appears to provide this list
  #define MYLIB_CXX11_UNIQUE_PTR 1
  ...

  // template aliases: MS at VS 2015 (v19.00); GCC at 4.7; Clang at 3.0; and Intel 12.1.
  #if (_MSC_VER >= 1900) || (__INTEL_COMPILER >= 1210)
  #  define MYLIB_CXX11_TEMPLATE_ALIAS 1
  #elif defined(__clang__)
  #  if (__has_feature(cxx_alias_templates))
  #    define MYLIB_CXX11_TEMPLATE_ALIAS 1
  #  endif
  #elif (__GNUC__ >= 5 || (__GNUC__ == 4 && __GNUC_MINOR__ >= 7))
  #  define MYLIB_CXX11_TEMPLATE_ALIAS 1
  #endif // template aliases

#endif // MYLIB_CXX11
```

***QUESTIONS***

Are there any other strategies to deal with C++11 and OS X?

Has anyone tried strategy (3)? If so, how much work was it?

---

***TESTING***

If you have access to OS X, then try the following to test the built in compiler, the standard, and GNU's `libstdc++` versus LLVM's `libc++`. After that, then test with a modern compiler by exporting `CXX=/opt/local/bin/clang++`.

```
$ cat test-clapple.cxx

// c++ -c test-clapple.cxx
// c++ -stdlib=libc++ -c test-clapple.cxx
// c++ -std=c++11 -c test-clapple.cxx
// c++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -c test-clapple.cxx

# include <memory>

// Manage auto_ptr warnings and deprecation in C++11
#if (__cplusplus >= 201103L) || (_MSC_VER >= 1900)
  template<typename T>
    using auto_ptr = std::unique_ptr<T>;
#else
    using std::auto_ptr;
#endif // C++11

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    return argc;
}
```

Comment: I'm nowhere near qualified to write a proper answer to this question, but #2 does seem like the best choice by far. Since you have to keep supporting C++03 anyway, it's not a catastrophe if one platform is stuck on only C++03. #3 seems like it'd be an absolute nightmare, though if you were to do it it'd probably be better to fix clang directly rather than hack around it.

Comment: Even option #3 does not give you the ability to interoperate with C++11 rvalue references. If you have to support C++03, it is likely that you have to be stuck with C++03.

Comment: @rwong - yeah, I think you are right. That probably requires compiler support...

Comment: Are you using an old version of Xcode, OS X, or Clang?  I use Xcode 5 on 10.9 and I'm pretty sure it is C++11 complete.  unique_ptr works std::move works, etc.  is it possible you are not passing the correct flag to Clang to make it use C++11 features?

Comment: @Matthew - Command Line Tools are installed. CLT uses the ancient gear. Also, I believe Xcode uses `--isysroot` to ensure it does not use the ancient version of the library Apple distributes.

Comment: If your Xcode command line tools don't use the latest version you are doing something wrong. See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2339/_index.html

Comment: @gnasher729 - well, I'm not sure what's going on. I have three OS X test machines: OS X 10.7, 10.8 and 10.9. They all exhibit the same behavior. If you have OS X available, try the little test program provided above with the 4 command lines. 1 or 2 of them should fail.

Comment: I'm glad someone else spoke up.  I think you are doing something wrong.  Try this: create a fresh install of 10.9. Install Xcode.  Install Command Line Tools.  create a C++ application.  Write C++11 code and run. It works I promise.

Comment: @MatthewJamesBriggs - OK, give me a few days. I need to get back on OS X 10.9 for testing. Does the simple test program above look OK to you? If the program is OK, then I will run the four compile test cases: `c++ -c test-clapple.cxx`, `c++ -stdlib=libc++ -c test-clapple.cxx`, `c++ -std=c++11 -c test-clapple.cxx`, `c++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -c test-clapple.cxx`.

Answer (score 2):

It is not MacOSX, it is the compiler that you use on it.

So, simply ***upgrade* your compiler**, perhaps by *building from* their *source code* a *recent* version of [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/) and/or [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler(s).

<sup>(you don't need permission from Apple to compile and use a newer compiler. You just need to take time to read and follow the build instructions; in a few hours you can get the latest release of GCC or of Clang running on your computer)</sup>

In december 2015, the current GCC is [GCC 5.3](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/), and the current Clang is [Clang 3.7](http://llvm.org/releases/download.html); and you could configure them so that the compiler would be called `g++-mine` or `clang++-mine`   if you want so.

Comment: Thanks, I get what you are saying. The problem is Apple supplies and maintains both of them (I probably shouldn't use *"maintain"* in that sentence since it appears Apple does not do that). So we don't control what/how most users configure their systems. Many simply use what Apple supplies.

Comment: My point is that you should yourself build the compilers from the distributed source code. You don't need Apple's permission to do that.